# Alternatives to Applet - File access required on client

Tags: java, security, file-io, applet, next-generation-plugin

I have to create a web application that should be able to access and process local files on the client side (a department). As this will have to be integrated with a legacy architecture, we have this:

- Files are distributed from a central repository to its destinations, basicly, to an IP. Nowadays, files are distributed to shared folders on every department.
- There must be a web application who can access those files and process them. It must be web as one of the objectives of the project is to replace the old Visual Basic desktop client, buggy and hard to distribute.

Besides, it shouldn't use propietary technology (as far as possible) or I would find lot of resistence to do the change.

Someone decided here to use an applet (a signed one) to get access to the files and process them, but i'm not sure this is the best way.

P.S.: I've been consulting stackoverflow and found this:

[Alternative to Java Applet for File System Access from Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504671/alternative-to-java-applet-for-file-system-access-from-web)

As this is my first question, I wasn't sure if I should add my question to it or open a new one. My question is mainly the same but I added some requirements to it (no desktop client) which maybe could give you more hints of what I need.

P.S. 2: Architecture (not the legacy part) is still under study. Any idea would be appreciated :)

Comment: "Someone decided here to use an applet (a signed one) to get access to the files and process them, but i'm not sure this is the best way, as it has been deprecated."  Neither applets nor code signing is 'deprecated'.

Comment: I added "as it has been deprecated" as I read it in a forum post this morning and then decided it was time to get rid of the applet. Thanks for the info, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your app on top of JSF 2 ([JSF 2 Introduction and Overview](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/jsf2/JSF2-Overview.pdf)) with rich client interface ([PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/), [ICEfaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/), [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) ).

Comment: Thanks @George :) I haven't use JSF yet, I will take a look.

Comment: I've been reading about JSF and Richfaces, but haven't found a way to access a file in client side and process it. The only way I've seen is to 'upload' each file I want to process from the client to the server side; anyhow, that wouldn't be suitable for our app, since those files shouldn't be uploaded to central server.

Comment: @Castilla1521 what kind of processing do you need? Do you need to read and write or you want to execute this files?

Comment: Our process involves deleting some files, moving others between folders and send some to other web services (printing services) who eventually would produce PDF's that we would show up in client's browser.

Comment: @Castilla1521 I think you can look at [Rich Ajax Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/), there are some demos on their site

Answer (score 0):

The 'JWS approach' can now work for an embedded applet, since JWS can be used to configure/launch embedded applets in a [Plug-In2 architecture JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jnlp-136707.html).

For an example of this approach, see my [demo. of the JNLP API file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

Comment: Mmm, JWS... haven't used it either. Thanks for the info @AndrewThompson, I will try it.

Comment: JWS not allows to build webapp. It allows to start java app on client machine from the internet using a web browser.

Comment: @George:  -1  Did you try reading either of the links before making that erroneous statement?  (And as an aside, a free-floating desktop app. can still consume web services and therefore be considered part of a 'web-app.'.)

Comment: I thought that Java Web Start and launching applets from JNLP is different things. I should study this more deeply