# My JApplet can't write to my APPDATA folder

Tags: java, access-denied, appdata, japplet

So yeah, I am making a Text-Based RPG, in the form of an applet. This applet writes to your APPDATA directory when opened. It works in the IDE, but when I try it in Firefox, it comes up with an error message. [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQn1m.png) is the link.

```
File otherWorldDirectory = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\.otherWorld");

if (!otherWorldDirectory.exists()) {
    //Adding the folder .otherWorld to the APPDATA
    otherWorldDirectory.mkdir();
    System.out.println("Directory '.otherWorld' created.");
} else {
    //The folder .otherWorld already exists.
    System.out.println("Directory '.otherWorld' is not created, it exists.");
}
```

Comment: You can't simply write to a local folder on the client machine - this is a security flaw. Revisit your design! See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504671/alternative-to-java-applet-for-file-system-access-from-web).

Comment: Then how? Do I need to sign the .jar file? Or just save it to a different folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the point of applets. They cannot access user's disk unless they are "trusted". You have to sign your applet to be able to access user's disk.

Answer (score 1):

> This applet writes to your APPDATA directory when opened.

Don't do that.  Mac. & *nix machines will not have it, & applets have access to a number of forms of persistence that is x-plat.

- Sand-boxed

  1. Cookies
  2. The JNLP API `PersistenceService` as seen in this [demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).
- Trusted

  1. `user.home` as an x-plat location to store information.
  2. `Preferences`
  3. All the ways open to sand-boxed apps.
  4. ...

Comment: I have no idea on what you just said.

Comment: Then it seems I have no way of helping you.  :(